# Thread that work in background of project until the end of program

Tags: ios, iphone, nsthread

I need to write a thread that do work in background of project.

when should I create it and where , for example in AppDelegate or others?

if I want to run thread when user do a job,for example when click on a button run a thread that work in background until the end of program,for this what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, a program never ends unless it crashes or the user turns their phone off. So running "until the end of program" is a very, very long time. Users will not thank you for emptying their battery.

It is most likely that what you are asking for is by far not the best possible solution, and will be rejected if you want to put your app into the app store. You should really explain what it is that you are actually trying to achieve.

In case you just posted the wrong question, the answer is "use GCD". If you don't know what GCD is, Google and Apple's documentation are your friend.

Comment: I want a thread for open a socket and listen to it,how should i do it,when?where?...